# how to subtract two resultant values in mysql

Tags: mysql, difference

Say I have a table `tableA` and my query is

```
select id, 
       if(cond1, value, 0) firstval, 
       if(cond2, value, 0) secondval, 
       firstval-secondval diff 
from tableA
```

The above query gives `Unknown column firstval in field list` error. I know I can calculate diff as `if(cond1, value, 0)-if(cond2, value, 0) diff` but i don't want to add condition again and without inner/sub queries.

**EDIT:** My abstract idea as follows

Table structure

```
id   |    type   |  recorddate  | value
=========================================
 1         A       2015-12-17       9
 2         B       2015-12-19       5
 3         A       2016-01-13       31
 4         B       2016-01-14       23
 5         A       2016-01-31       44
 6         B       2016-02-07       38
```

and so on...

Query:

```
 select 
    type, 
    if(max(recorddate), value, 0) firstval, 
    if(secondmax(recorddate), value, 0) secndval, 
    firstval-secndval diff 
 from table 
 where month(recorddate)=1
 group by type with rollup
```

Resultant table based on above query:

```
type  | firstval  |  secndval  |  diff
======================================
 A      44           31          13
 B      23           5           18
Total   67           36          31
```

Comment: What's wrong with using sub queries? Why don't you want that? Otherwise I don't think you can do it.

Comment: if there is a sub query, we can't use `group by with rollup`... Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, you show us the full problem?

Comment: What are you grouping on? Please define all of your requirements and the constraints in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add sub-query

```
select *, firstval-secondval diff 
   from 
     (select id, if(cond1, value, 0) firstval, if(cond2, value, 0) secondval
        from tableA
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get subtract two resultant values. Am i right?

So that for firstval check with one condition if condition true then get that value otherwise firstval value is 0. Do the same for secondval also. So that you will not get unknown column error. First of all you should have column name firstval and secondval.

```
Select firstval-secondval as total from tableA;
```

It will work for simple subtract.